# How to get text present in <td> </td> in Proctractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

How to get text present in the second td.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="s in systemSettings" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">License Key</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">rashmi123</td>
        <td align="center">
            <div data-ng-show="s.readOnly" class="text-warning ng-hide">read only</div>
            <div data-ng-show="!s.readOnly"> <a href="" data-ng-click="onSettingEdit(s)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> </a> </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have tried to get it by using by

```
  expect(element("tr:nth-child(2) td.ng-binding:nth-child(2)").getInnerHtml()).toBe("rashmi123");
```

but it is giving  Invalid locator error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element locator should contain the types like - `xpath`, `css`, etc...

```
expect(element(by.css("tr:nth-child(2) td.ng-binding:nth-child(2)")).getInnerHtml()).toBe("rashmi123");
```

Also you can use `.getText()` to get the text of an element instead of getInnerHtml.

```
var ele = element(by.css("tr:nth-child(2) td.ng-binding:nth-child(2)"));
expect(ele.getText()).toBe("rashmi123");
```

OR use the short form provided by protractor for `element(by.css())` => `$()`

```
var ele = $("tr:nth-child(2) td.ng-binding:nth-child(2)");
expect(ele.getText()).toBe("rashmi123");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Girish Sortur -What a silly mistake I have done. Thank you very much for pointing me.